# Function with onClick() is returning the data on next click but not on same click

Tags: android, function, onclick, return-value

I am developing my first application and it is kind of game I am trying to develop. I am facing an issue with the return of desired data from a fuction containing onclick.
below is the code which calls the function to return the task_tb_done string.

```
name_win_player_ch_screen.setText(player2_name);
        name_lost_player_ch_screen.setText(player1_name);
        String challenge2= challenge_selector(task_type);
        task_tb_done.setText(player1_name+" "+challenge2);
        challenge2="";
```

and here is the code which handles that request. The challenge which is being assigned in the while conditional loop is returned but not immediately as it should be but it returns the value next time this part of the function is called. I think there is some problem with OnClik methods because in other challenge selections I am not using onClicks and they are giving me the perfect values in return immediately.

```
 else if(task_type.equals("Truth or Dare")){


        firstplayer_screen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        secondplayer_screen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        game_screen_table.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        truth_or_dare_selection_screen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //A pop up to ask Either they want a truth or dare
        //upon selection will give them task to do or to tell the truth.

        truth_select_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                truesize =  truth.length;

                int i = (int) (Math.random() * ((truesize - 0) + 1));
                if(i<=truesize) {
                    c=1;
                    toast.setText("Hey" + truth[i]);
                    toast.show();
                    challenge = truth[i];
                    truth_or_dare_selection_screen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    challenge_selector(task_type);
                    toast.setText("Please Click again");
                    c=0;
                    toast.show();

                }
            }
        });
        dare_select_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                daresize =  dare.length;

                int i = (int) (Math.random() * ((daresize - 0) + 1));

                if(i<=truesize) {
                    c=1;

                    toast.setText("Hey" + dare[i]);
                    toast.show();
                    challenge = dare[i];
                    truth_or_dare_selection_screen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    challenge_selector(task_type);
                    toast.setText("Please Click again");
                    c=0;
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });

        while (c==1) {
            c=0;
            truth_or_dare_selection_screen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return challenge;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of 'c' variable the first time it executes?
If it is not 1, it won't enter inside the while loop and it won't return the challenge.

If you want to stay inside the while loop until the user clicks on one of the buttons, you should try this:

```
while (c != 1) {

}
return challenge;
```

This way, it will be looping indefinitely until the user clicks (c = 1), then the loop will end and you will reach the 'return challenge'.

Although you should consider using a callback for this kind of behavior, and setting the OnClickListeners in your Activity onCreate method.

Comment: Actually I am trying to do the opposite as you are mentioning. When If condition is true I get a popup to make a decision. On making a decision I want to enter in while loop like in onclick when the value of c is made 1.

Comment: I would need to see the full class, I don't really uderstand when all that code is being invoked.
As I stated before, you should (usually) set the listeners in the onCreate method of your Activity.
You shouldn't either have a return statement inside a while loop (your while is just an if as it is right now).

If you show us more code maybe I can help you further.